# Regular expression to count how many newlines (\n) there are in a string?

Tags: regex, actionscript, newline

I'm trying to find the number of newlines (\n) in a string using the Actionscript 3.0 RegExp engine.  Using the string.match function and RegExp("\n","g") does not find the newlines in a string which contains newlines.  Is there something I need to add to the pattern or something else that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the newlines actually are `\n`? Maybe you have `\r` in your data instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `match(/\r?\n/g)`. It looks like the `match()` functionality for JavaScript is equal that of ActionScript.

Comment: match("\n") should work as well, according to Adobe's API docs. The match method will return an array, so you'll need to do someString.match("\n").length

Comment: @Jeremy White, Well, if he only uses what you recommended, he will only get 1 hit, since he should be using a global switch.

Comment: @Tomalak, Then perhaps newline is carriage return `\r\n` or something, did an update just in case.

Comment: After some testing, I think I've pinpointed the issue.  It's not a problem with the expression, it works on a normal string with "\n".  But when you use the concat function to add that string to a second string and run the reg exp on the second string, it does not find the newline.  I'm not sure why that is the case, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
match(/$/mg).length
```